# Get the values of the object in the indexedDB with lawndart

Tags: dart, indexeddb, dart-html

I'm creating a function to store data in `IndexedDB`, keeping an Object that consists of a Map to which I assign a key.

With the key, I get the value of the object, but it's a `LinkedHashMap` and not a `Map` and when I try to access the data inside the object, I always get *null* as response. I've read the API docs, but I'm new on this and I don't see how to make it work.

What I intend to do is to get the data from the indexedDb and assign it to an object to be able to manipulate it.

Thanks a lot in advance !!!

```dart
  /**
   *  Opens the database, erases it and saves some info
   */
  void openDB(var db) {
    Map ourList = {'title':'A random title',
                     'text':'Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna.',
                     'data':'2013'};
    Map ourList2 = {
                      'title':'Another random title',
                      'text':'Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna.',
                      'data':'2014'};
    db.open()
      .then((_) => db.nuke()) /// Erases all the data in the DB
      .then((_) => db.save(ourList, '1')) /// Saves an object in the DB
      .then((_) => db.save(ourList2, '2'));
    print('openDB() was executed'); /// Console control
    getTheData(db);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the data from the DB JUST AN EXAMPLE !! 
   */

  void  getTheData(var db){
    Map dbData; /// dbData = null for definition
    db.open() /// lawndart method
      .then((_) => db.getByKey('1')) /// Gets a value depending on the Key
      .then((value) => print(value)); /// Prints the value of the key
    db.open()
      .then((_) => db.getByKey('2'))
      .then((value) => print(value)); /// To check != values, use different methods
    db.open()
      .then((_) => db.getByKey('2'))
      .then((value) => print(value.runtimeType)); /// prints the Type of var

  /**
    *  What type of variable it is: _LinkedHashMap
    *  Classes implement the Map interface and offers mostly the same functionality.
    *  LinkedHashMap will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map
   */
    print('getTheData() was executed');/// Console control
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use 'Map' you get a linked hash map implementation as a default.

This code :-

```dart
print('openDB() was executed'); /// Console control
getTheData(db);
```

should be inside your last 'then' statement, your accessing the db before the storage has happened.

Comment: Thanks! But what I intend to do is to get the data from the indexedDb and assign it to an object to be able to manipulate it. Sorry if my question was not clear and thanks again for your time.

Comment: I think the answer is still accurate. You may take a look at this doc https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/.
`getTheData()` is executed **before** the `nuke` and the 2 succeeding `save` methods.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer ! if that is happening, then why i'm able, to print the value obtained by the key but not to assign it to a variable ? I'm a little bit confused with futures